# Passing parameters to Powershell not working

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I have a powershell script which runs under elevated privileges as given here https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2014/01/using-runwithelevatedprivileges-in-sharepoint-powershell.html as the script is running some powershell commands on SharePoint.

The problem I am experiencing is trying to pass some parameters to the function. When I run the script it is not failing but there is no output.

I have set outside of the function name the param with two variables names I want to use. The variable names are passed into the function. This runs but no result. Along with other ways.

If I don't set any parameters and set the variable values as hard coded, then bingo the script works and I get a result.

The code I am wrapping around the run as elevated privileges is this code https://www.netwrix.com/how_to_get_sharepoint_permissions_report.html

So, how do you pass in parameters to a function in script using the SharePoint run as elevated privileges?

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76837689/edit) your question to include the code you are using, not just a link to a site you referenced.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I have no SharePoint experience; if better solutions exist, do tell us.

- [`[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity]::RunWithElevatedPrivileges()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ms439682(v=office.14)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) has only *one* parameter, namely a `delegate` instance to which *no* parameters are passed.
- Thus, there is also no way to pass parameters to a PowerShell [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) acting as such a delegate.
- A script block that *runs in the same PowerShell runspace* (which implies the same thread) would *implicitly* have access to the caller's variables (due to PowerShell's dynamic scoping), but this seems *not* to be the case in your scenario.

---

A - **limited and cumbersome** - **workaround** is to construct your script block *as a string*, using *string interpolation* to "bake in" (embed in the source code) the values you want to pass as arguments.

The **major limitation** is:

- It only works for values of .NET data types that have *literal* source-code representations (and the embedded values are invariably *copies* of the original values).

This isn't much better than hard-coding values directly in the script block, but it does allow you to embed values not known at design time, and it amounts to a more maintainable solution.

The following is a **minimal example** that demonstrates the technique, using [`[scriptblock]::Create()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.Create) with an expandable (interpolating) [here-string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#here-strings):

```bash
# A "parameter" (value) that you want to embed in the script block.
$myParam = 'Hello, world.'

# Create the script block's source code *as a string*, allowing you to
# use string interpolation.
$scriptBlockSourceCode = @"
  # Use string interpolation to embed the value of $myParam
  # Note: All $ characters to be preserved as part of the resulting 
  #       code must be escaped as `$
  `$myParam = '$myParam'

  # Demonstrate that the value was successfully embedded.
  Write-Verbose -Verbose ('The value of `$myParam is: ' + `$myParam)
"@

# Construct the script block from the source codde:
$scriptBlock = [scriptblock]::Create($scriptBlockSourceCode)

# For demo purposes, use a dummy call that involves a delegate in lieu
# of `[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity]::RunWithElevatedPrivileges()`, 
# just to demonstrate that the value was correctly embedded.
[Array]::Find(
   @(1), 
  [Predicate[object]] $scriptBlock
)
```

Note:

- Reference variables whose values you want to embed by name (e.g., `$myParam`); if you need to embed the value of an *expression*, enclose the reference in `$(...)` (e.g., `$($myParam.SomeProperty)`) - for a comprehensive overview of PowerShell's string interpolation, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375).
- All `$` characters that must be retained as such as part of the resulting source code must be escaped as `` `$ `` to prevent up-front expansion.
- You need to ensure that expanded value works syntactically in the resulting source code, which notably means using embedded quoting (e.g., `'$myParam'`) for embedded *string* values; if the value to embed contains quoting characters of the same type itself, you'll have to escape them (`''` inside `'...'`, `` `" `` inside `"..."`).

Answer (score 0):

No need, all had to do was to use read-host inside the delegate and record the input when the user reaches that point